# 2VertexDisjointPaths ≤p SimpleCycle

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, path

Given the following problems:

**2VertexDisjointPaths:**

**Given:** a directed Graph $G$ und vertices $s1, s2, t1, t2$.

**Question:** Do paths $p1$ from $s1$ to $t1$ and $p2$ from $s2$ to $t2$ exist if $p1$ and $p2$ are vertex disjoint? Vertex disjoint meaning if $p1$ uses a vertex $p2$ can't use it and vice versa.

**SimpleCycle:**

**Given:** a directed Graph $G$ and two edges $e1, e2$ of $G$.

**Question:** Is there a directed circle in G, which goes through e1 and e2?

**Show that SC is np-complete by using that 2VDP is np-complete.**

I know you have to reduce 2VDP to SC but I don't know the mapping function which will map the input of 2VDP to the input of SC. In other words I don't know the basic idea yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the edges: $(t_1,s_2)$ and $(t_2,s_1)$ to the graph $G$ if they are not there already. Let the new graph be $G'$. For $SC$ problem, take $e_1  = (t_1,s_2)$ and $e_2 = (t_2,s_1)$ and solve it on $G'$.